# I am trying to rearrange sections of a picture in matlab

Tags: matlab

here is the assignment: 
Open humpty_mixed.gif (2D image) and do what all of the king’s horses and men could not do – put humpty back together again. The image is 600x412 and split evenly  along the row and columns. (Note: We may use the imread(), imshow(), and imwrite() commands here.)

the picture is sectioned off in 4 rows and 4 columns, could someone help me get started, i'm stuck

Comment: Are you trying to automate this, or is it like a puzzle for the user to do?

Comment: not going to lie, i have no idea what i am doing or even how to get started, all i managed to do was turn the image black and overwrite the original

Comment: Do you know how many pieces you have in total, in rows and in columns? Were they rotated?

Answer (score 0):

b=imread('humpty_mixed.gif');
imshow('humpty_mixed.gif')

%that should get you started.oh by the way this is cheating you will recieve a zero!

a=b:

imshow(a)